# Microsoft.Data.Services.Client Nuget package trying to install wrong dependencies

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

In Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 (15.3), with latest Nuget (4.3.0.4339), I am trying to upgrade `Microsoft.Data.Edm` from `5.6.4 --> 5.8.2`.

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.8.2' with respect to project 'ConsoleApps\FeedProvider', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 1.98 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.8.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.8.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.8.2'
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.0136869
========== Finished ==========
```

On Nuget site [Edm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Edm/) package does not list any dependencies. When confirmation window shows up it lists dependencies under installing section, which seem to be pulled from [Microsoft.Data.Services.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/) `.NETStandard 1.1` list of dependencies:

[image: Nuget Screenshot]

I am clearly not using .NETStandard 1.1 for the project in question (nor any other project in this solution), as you can see if you scroll top log to the right `with respect to project 'ConsoleApps\FeedProvider', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'`

Does anyone know what's up, or how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what's up, or how to get around this problem?

**Update answer** according to the CrnaStena`s comment.

This package should be a problematic package. According to the Dependencies of the package `Microsoft.Data.Services.Client`：

[image]

We can notice that the dependencies `Microsoft.Data.Edm` has **no framework specific**. In this condition, NuGet will install the dependencies in the framework .NET Standard, Version=1.1. That why we got that confirmation window shows up the error dependencies.

In order to track this issue, I have create a new issue on GitHub:

[NuGet install the wrong dependecies](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/953)

To resolve this issue, I downloaded this package and add the dependence `Microsoft.Data.Edm` in to the .net framework 4.0 by NuGet Package Explorer.

[image]

**Update**:

Since there is a new version released:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/5.8.3

I have verified it, and it works fine.

Then save this package to the local feed, install the package from local feed.

Comment: I get dependencies between `Services.Client` and `Edm`, what I don't get is why is it installing `.NETStandard 1.1` dependencies, which I am not using.

Comment: @CrnaStena, Thanks for your reply and sorry for my understanding. I think this package should be a  problematic package so I report it on github and provide a workaround. hope this can give you some help.

Comment: Thanks, I will see about implementing your workaround until issue is resolved by Microsoft OData team, or at least they explain their thinking.

Comment: @CrnaStena, there is a new version released v5.8.3, you can check the update in the answer for detail.

Comment: Yes, 5.8.3 version works as I expected without installing wrong dependencies. Thanks.